# React Redux actions and reducer mapping error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im still pretty new to using Redux and Im having an issue trying to tie my action and reducer together properly to another component. So Im just trying something simple like adding a comment to a post. The user types in their name then their comment and I would like it to show both. Im trying to find the best way to write this inside my reducer.

Here is my action

```
export const ADD_COMMENT = 'ADD_COMMENT';
export const addComment = (author, comment) => ({
 type: ADD_COMMENT,
  author,
  comment
});
```

Here is my comments.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CommentForm from './comment-form';

export function Comments(props) {
 const comments = props.comments.map((comment, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
        <div className="author">{comment.author} says:</div>
        <div className="comment">{comment.comment}</div>
    </li>
));
return (
    <section>
        <h2>Comments</h2>
        {comments.length ? <ul>{comments}</ul> : <div>No comments</div>}
        <h3>Add a comment</h3>
        <CommentForm />
    </section>
);
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
comments: state.comments
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Comments);
```

Here is my reducer.js

```
import {ADD_COMMENT} from './actions';

const initialState = {
 comments: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
 if(action.type === ADD_COMMENT){
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        comments: action.comments
    });
}

return state;
}
```

The way I have it right now, Im getting a "Cannot read property map of undefined. Ive tried adding author:'' to my initialState and author: action.author down in the function in my reducer and still the same thing. So I know that my issue has to do with how Im writing my reducer.

Comment: How are you importing the Comments component

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626245/why-do-i-get-a-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined/52626342#52626342

Answer (score 0):

The below solution will help you get the comments from reducer and render it in component if you have comments available otherwise `no comments` will be displayed

This solution resolves below issue with all the corrections made in Comments.js, actions and reducer

> Cannot read property map of undefined

Try to add comment id as a key to li element instead of index. Index always should be second choice when you don’t have unique id from data

**Update:**

You have a typo error in reducer you need to call action.comment but you are calling action.comments. Check the corrected below

```
import {ADD_COMMENT} from './actions';
const initialState = {
 comments: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  if(action.type === ADD_COMMENT){
    state.comments = action.comment;
    return state;
  }else{
     return state;
  }
}
```

corrected comments.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CommentForm from './comment-form';

export function Comments(props) {
return (
    <section>
        <h2>Comments</h2>
         <ul>
        {Array.isArray(props.comments) && props.comments.length > 0 && props.comments.map((comment, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
         <div className="author">{comment.author} says:              </div>
          <div className="comment">{comment.comment}</div>
        </li>
   ))}
    </ul>

    {!Array.isArray(props.comments) && <div>No comments</div>}
        <h3>Add a comment</h3>
        <CommentForm />
    </section>
);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
 return {"comments": state.comments}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Comments);
```

Comment: Dont get an error. But just nothing happens. The text input fields get reset but no comment shows.

Comment: Ok what do u get in console when u do console.log(props.comments); do u get the data here?

Comment: No. Im getting undefined.

Comment: @D.Graves try updating the reducer as I suggested in my updated answer. It should work

Comment: Should I be including author inside of my reducer somewhere?

Comment: If you want author in your component then you can include otherwise not mandatory

Comment: @D.Graves you had an issue in comments.js file as well. Check my updated answer. In mapStateToProps you are not returning comments

Comment: When I try to add return, it throws an error. It isnt liking the return {comments: state.comments}

Comment: @D.Graves I just edited mapStateToProps please give a try now

Comment: Its just a syntax error. I get a failed to compile. Syntax error: return is a reserved word

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181729/discussion-between-think-twice-and-d-graves).